# Oracle Apex redirect page from value set from select List

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

DB oracle: 11g
APex  4.2.6.00.03

I Have a Select list with page names displayed and page number as the value.
so for example

displayed: reports/
value: 15

displayed: Config/
value: 18

displayed: home/
value: 1

I also have a Dynamic action which sets the page number from the select list. Once a button is press
and also placed in Page items to submit

```
SELECT page FROM getPage
 where Var = :P10_Page
```

How do I do a page redirect from the page number from above. Im stumpped.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your select list returns the actual page numbers you want this is simple.  Just edit the select list item and set the Page Action when Value Changed setting to "Redirect to Page (based on selected value)":

[image]

See [my demo on apex.oracle.com](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=22644:102).

You seem to have the select list returning one number which you then look up in a table to get a different number.  I don't understand why that would be necessary?

Comment: Many thanks completely forgot about the page number direct. I way over did that